# Avoid duplicate in $http.get email and mobile number

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a form with name, email, mobilenumber ... and i have successfully posted to server. i can create multiple users with same mobilenumber and email but my aim is to avoid duplicate mobilenumber and email only one time an user can create a user with one mobilenumber and email.

```
    var stringNumberURL= "http://port/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/ADUser?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k&_where=opcrmMobile=%27";
    var lastStringURL= "%27";
    var middelStringMobileNumber= userdata.data["opcrmMobile"];
    console.log(middelStringMobileNumber);

    var stringEmailURL="http://port/easycloud1/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/ADUser?l=saiy5k&p=saiy5k&_where=email=%27";
    var middelStringEmailID=userdata.data["email"];
    console.log(middelStringEmailID);

    var mobileNumberURL=stringNumberURL.concat(middelStringMobileNumber,lastStringURL);
    console.log(mobileNumberURL);

    var email_idURL=stringEmailURL.concat(middelStringEmailID,lastStringURL);
    console.log(email_idURL);

        $http.get(mobileNumberURL) 
        .success(function(response){
            alert("mobilenumber is already exist");
        })            
        .error(function(response){
            $http.get(email_idURL) 
            .success(function(response){
                alert("eamil-id already exist");
            })
            .error(function(response){
                onLeadCreate();
            })
        });
```

but when i try this code my function always invokes only the success part.and here %27 indicates  ** " **  (doubel code symbol or single code symbol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code,

```
if (response.response.data.length !== 0) {
    alert("mobilenumber is already exist");
} else if (response.response.data.length == 0) {
    //Your Content goes here    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will always trigger the success callback if the GET request was successful. You need to check if it's a duplicate in the backend and pass the status inside the callback response.

```
.success(function(response){
    if ('undefined' !== typeof response.error) {
         if ('duplicate' === response.error) { 
             // handle duplicate error
         }
    }
})
```

Comment: please can you explain me about the condition that you give in if

Comment: the check for duplicates must be checked on the back end - you simply construct a json response on the back end and pass it back to the front end as a success

Comment: sorry i need to check in front end

Comment: i think i need to give an if condition to check opcrmMobile number

Comment: but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Show me your responce data?